# jQuery Parent change inner HTML

Tags: jquery, parent, innerhtml

I got this so far:

```
$('.event-tools a').click(function() 
{
    var status = $(this).attr('id');
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8888/update/test.php",
        data: "rsvp=" + status + '&id=' + id,
        success: function()
        {
            $(this).parent().html(status);
            //alert(status);
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert('failz');
        }
    });
});
```

With this:

```
<span class="rsvp" id="1">
    <a href="#" class="rsvp" id="Attending">Attending</a>
    <a href="#" class="rsvp" id="Maybe Attending">Maybe Attending</a>
    <a href="#" class="rsvp" id="Not Attending">Not Attending</a>
</span>
```

When I click on one of them and use the `alert()` it works by prompting the alert box, however, when I use the `$(this).parent().html(status);` on the `success:` event, it doesn't change the HTML with the `status`...

Comment: I don't think your ids are valid ids...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` inside your success-function does not have the same scope as outside of it, since JavaScript has function scope. You need to do something like this to preserve the original value of the outer function's `this`:

```
var self = this;
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function() {
        $(self).parent().html(status);
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could use jQuery's [`.proxy()`-method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy):

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: $.proxy(function() {
        $(this).parent().html(status);
    }, this)
});
```

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that, the proxy works awesome. Cheers for that! (5 minutes till I can accept the answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this

JS:

```
$('.event-tools a').click(function(ev) 
{
    ev.stopPropagation()

    var status = $(this).attr('id'),
        id = $(this).parent().attr('id'),
        myparent = $(this).parent();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8888/update/test.php",
        data: "rsvp=" + status + '&id=' + id,
        success: function()
        {
            $(myparent).parent().html(status);
            //alert(status);
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert('failz');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<span class="event-tools" id="1"><!-- this has class = "rsvp" -->
    <a href="#" class="rsvp" id="Attending">Attending</a>
    <a href="#" class="rsvp" id="Maybe Attending">Maybe Attending</a>
    <a href="#" class="rsvp" id="Not Attending">Not Attending</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't change the inner HTML.